# openpyxl - adding new rows in excel file with merged cell existing

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, python-2.7, openpyxl

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20JFY.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d7m6.png)

So, I was trying to add 6 rows into the excelsheet.
And I used 
openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.insert_rows(ws,idx=0,amount=6) 
to help me accomplish the task. 
This line works perfect with normal excel file.

But, when it comes to the excel file contained merged cells. The program will  not working properly just like the image I attached.

Could someone give me some ideas about how to solve the issue. I ran out all the ideas and need some inspirations.

Thank you very much for whoever answers my questions!!

Comment: Where do you want to insert the 6 rows? Before the "data data data data" row , or after? Can you provide a picture of the **Expected** result of where the rows should appear?

Comment: I am trying to add 6 new empty rows before the “data data data” thanks for helping me out:)

Comment: As far as I can see, the openpyxl insert_rows doesn't behave the same way it would do if you were to insert them manually, you can try some script to "shift" the cells down, or some vba script, I will try something later

Comment: Thanks for giving me an update!! I have not found any straightforward way to 'shift' the cell down.

Comment: Have a look [Here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.6/_modules/openpyxl/worksheet/cell_range.html#CellRange) in the meantime. CellRange has a function Shift that should allow you to shift the Range by a number of rows, but I can't get it to assign the Range to the Sheet with values.

Comment: Have you got any solution? I still can not figure out the solution.

Comment: Sadly no, I haven't got time tbh, I'll look into it this weekend.

Comment: No problem! Hopefully, you will have time to help me solve the issue. You have a good weekend:)

Comment: I found the answer to your question, I'm writing it soon. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's say you want to add 3 rows at the top of your table, you'll first have to shift down the merged cells and then insert the rows; 
For this we are going to use the `shift(col_shift=0, row_shift=0)` method;

```
Help on method shift in module openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range:

shift(col_shift=0, row_shift=0) method of openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range.CellRange instance
    Shift the range according to the shift values (*col_shift*, *row_shift*).

    :type col_shift: int
    :param col_shift: number of columns to be moved by, can be negative
    :type row_shift: int
    :param row_shift: number of rows to be moved by, can be negative
    :raise: :class:`ValueError` if any row or column index < 1
```

---

The number of rows you want to insert must coincide with the numbers of rows you shift;
So for your example you'll just have to:

```
merged_cells_range = ws.merged_cells.ranges
for merged_cell in merged_cells_range:
    merged_cell.shift(0,3)
ws.insert_rows(1,3)
```

So in the end the merged cells are preserved
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for providing me with the solutions. Your solution works for me very well!! You are a genius:)  Only a few lines of code solved my issue perfectly.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Sorry if it took me a while but I was busy, Have nice week!