How to use openpyxl to insert new row and keep the formatting of the new row as its last row in table?
I have faced an issue of insert new row in the excel file at the same time keeping its formatting/style
I did try to use the openpyxl's insert new row
conv_ws.insert_rows(idx=14,amount=1)
The new row will not have the same format as in the picture show:
Image after insert new row
As u guys can see the new row is added in row 14, but that row won't keep the format as its last row in the same table.
How can I keep the new row's format is the same as its last row?

The CopyOrigin feature is a function of the Excel app. Openpyxl edits XML files only. If you want to use that feature you'll need to use a module that edits workbooks under Excel, like Xlwings or Win32com. If you want to use Openpyxl then you'll have to apply the necessary formatting to the required cells.

Adding a row won't copy the style, but you can do it yourself.
Each cell has accessible styles (see the documentation) you can copy and apply on another one with something like :
from copy import copy

new_cell.font = copy(source_cell.font)
new_cell.border = copy(source_cell.border)
new_cell.fill= copy(source_cell.fill)
new_cell.alignment = copy(source_cell.alignment)
new_cell.number_format = copy(source_cell.number_format)
new_cell.protection = copy(source_cell.protection)

So you could create a copy_row_format function to automatically copy style from previous row (edit: and handle merged cells beneath added rows):
import openpyxl
from copy import copy

def copy_row_format(ws, source_row, new_row):

    for col in range(1, ws.max_column + 1):

        source_cell = ws.cell(row=source_row, column=col)
        new_cell = ws.cell(row=new_row, column=col)
        
        new_cell.font = copy(source_cell.font)
        new_cell.border = copy(source_cell.border)
        new_cell.fill= copy(source_cell.fill)
        new_cell.alignment = copy(source_cell.alignment)
        new_cell.number_format = copy(source_cell.number_format)
        new_cell.protection = copy(source_cell.protection)

filename = 'yourfile.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'yoursheet'
row_index = 14
nb_rows_to_add = 3

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
conv_ws = wb[sheet_name]

merged_cells_range = conv_ws.merged_cells.ranges
for merged_cell in merged_cells_range:
    min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = openpyxl.utils.range_boundaries(str(merged_cell))
    if min_row >= row_index:
        merged_cell.shift(0, nb_rows_to_add)

conv_ws.insert_rows(row_index, amount=nb_rows_to_add)

for i in range(nb_rows_to_add):
    copy_row_format(conv_ws, row_index + nb_rows_to_add, row_index + i)

print(conv_ws.max_column)

wb.save(filename)


Hi, I've tried ur solution, and this is the result:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'StyleProxy'

Sorry made a mistake, you have to use copy fucntion to get and set attributes because the dictionnary is not directly reachable. Edited my answer.

It works! Thanks for your help

But there is one issue, that I have found, which if I add a new row, those rows under the new adding row's value will move down also but not along with their row format. Which would cause a problem, if those rows under new adding got merge cell, the new adding row will inherit the merged cell format, and those rows under new adding row will lose their merged cell format

you can take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51980431/19827373 i will edit my answer to handle merged cells
